# Display summary of a database value on Notion

Tags: notion

I have a database in Notion that looks something like this:

[image]

I want to create a page where I can display the sum of the Net Income column but all I see are views that don't fit my goal, is there a way I can display it on a page?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask/#:~:text=Have%20you%20thoroughly%20searched%20for%20an%20answer) before asking your question? Have you reviewed [Notion Support: Using database views](https://www.notion.so/help/guides/using-database-views)?  See how do I [ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask/)

Comment: I did, if you watch the video you will see that none of the view displayed fit my question, as previously mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This is not really found in the documentation but one can create a summary table that relates to the other tables, in which you can use rollups to compute them. This info can then be used on a page at the DB. Here is my example:

This is the DB I've created:

[image]

And now I can access the info from the Budged dashboard page:

[image]